# GAPI Google analytics API PHP get Events

Tags: php, google-analytics, google-api-js-client

I want to get events from my google analytics account.

This is how looks my PHP controller:

```
$dimensions  = array('eventAction');
        $metrics     = array('visits','totalEvents','uniqueEvents', 'eventsPerVisitWithEvent');
        $sort_metric = '-totalEvents';

        $ga->requestReportData($ga_profile_id,
            $dimensions,
            $metrics,
            $sort_metric,


            $filter='ga:eventAction==link' ,
            $dateWStart,
            $dateEnd,
            $start_index=1,
            $max_results=50);
```

And it gets me an empty value.

Meaby $filter is wrong? What filter must refers to?

My event category name is: **link**  and I check it in
 **google analytics->behavior->events->Altogether**

Comment: Wouldn't you need the "ga:" prefix in your dimensions and metrics names ?